# How to write an exception to allow application to run if database is not found?

Tags: java, exception, cloud-foundry

I currently have a jdbcUrl oracle database binded to my cloud foundry application. I want my application to be able to build and run even if the service is not binded. Meaning it would throw a null exception, but still allow the app to run. (just wouldn't display any data).

**SQLREPO**

```
@Repository
public class myTableRepo {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<myTable_Model> getAll(String id) {

        String sql = "SELECT * from myTable order by last_modified desc";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 
                new myTableRowMapper());
   }
    }
```

**RowMapper class**

```
class myTableRowMapper implements RowMapper<myTable_Model>
{
    @Override
    public myTable_Model mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        myTable_Model model = new myTable_Model();

        model.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        model.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        model.setlast_modified(rs.getString("last_modified"));

        return model;
    }
}
```

How would I write an exception if database is not found. Catch it and continue my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could catch only exceptions related to SQL connection and then just log it.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
 public List<myTable_Model> getAll(String id) {
   List<myTable_Model> result = new ArrayList<>();
   try {
       String sql = "SELECT * from myTable order by last_modified desc";
       result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Clone_HistoryRowMapper());
   }
   catch(SQLException ex) {
      logger.log("An error happened when interacting to the database.", ex)
   }
   return result;
 }
```

This way the app would continue if an error only related to SQL happens and stop id some other error occurs.

Comment: If set a try catch like example you provided. My sql variable will be undefined. When returning jdbcTemplate.query.

Comment: I think your `sql` variable will be deleted whenever the code exits `getAll` method. I just updated the example in order to return empty list if you get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Spring, so I would suggest that you take a look at profiles.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles

With profiles, you can configure a different set of beans for different environments.  For example, you could configure a "local" profile that runs and configures an in-memory database, and you can configure a "cloud" profile for when your app is running on Cloud Foundry.  When you deploy your app to Cloud Foundry, the Java build pack will activate the "cloud" profile automatically (this can work without CF too, you just manually have to enable the profile).  Instructions for enabling profiles are here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-enable

Spring Boot makes enabling profiles [even easier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).  It also allows you to [configure conditional beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-bean-conditions), for example, if bean A doesn't exist then configure X.  This way you could have a default in-memory database that is configured if no other datasource is configured.